# Image button in android

Tags: android

Is that possible to make an image in a button like that, or I have to create this image and make it an image button?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4jMy.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some code and maybe an image of where you are stuck and we will help you along. In case you have no idea where to start, there are two things you can try. 1 - Make a button and use drawableStart or drawableEnd. 2 - Make a TextView with drawableStart or drawableEnd and apply a custom style to match the image.

Comment: Also please mention if you're looking for a composebased solution or a viewbased one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.